# Group records by time intervals based on other entries (Gaps and islands)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timestamp, grouping

Using SQL Server 2012, I have the following activity table with data ordered by `IP, Timestamp, User`:

#### Sample table

```
---------------------------------------------
| Timestamp        | IP            | User   |
|------------------|---------------|--------|
| 2018-03-13 08:30 | 192.168.0.10  | user3  |
| 2018-03-14 01:30 | 192.168.0.10  | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 07:00 | 192.168.0.10  | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 10:10 | 192.168.0.10  | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 11:00 | 192.168.0.10  | user10 |
| 2018-03-14 13:50 | 192.168.0.10  | user10 |
| 2018-03-14 18:00 | 192.168.0.10  | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 01:30 | 192.168.0.150 | user1  |
| 2018-03-15 08:00 | 192.168.0.170 | user1  |
| 2018-03-15 12:20 | 192.168.0.170 | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 10:00 | 192.168.0.20  | user2  |
| 2018-03-14 15:30 | 192.168.0.20  | user2  |
| 2018-03-14 17:30 | 192.168.0.20  | user2  |
---------------------------------------------
```

I would like to know the time intervals in which users were connected from the recorded IPs, with the desired output being as follows:

#### Desired output

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| From             | To               | IP            | User   |
|------------------|------------------|---------------|--------|
| 2018-03-13 08:30 | 2018-03-13 08:30 | 192.168.0.10  | user3  |
| 2018-03-14 01:30 | 2018-03-14 10:10 | 192.168.0.10  | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 11:00 | 2018-03-14 13:50 | 192.168.0.10  | user10 |
| 2018-03-14 18:00 | 2018-03-14 18:00 | 192.168.0.10  | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 01:30 | 2018-03-14 01:30 | 192.168.0.150 | user1  |
| 2018-03-15 08:00 | 2018-03-15 12:20 | 192.168.0.170 | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 10:00 | 2018-03-14 17:30 | 192.168.0.20  | user2  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notably in this example, `user1` has recorded two time intervals for IP `192.168.0.10`, from `2018-03-14 01:30` to `2018-03-14 10:10` and from `2018-03-14 18:00` to `2018-03-14 18:00`, therefore the grouping should not take only the minimum and maximum timestamps for that `IP, User` pair.

So far the queries built have the only flaw is the one mentioned above – grouping the two entries into one, from `2018-03-14 01:30` to `2018-03-14 18:00`.

#### Current queries

```
SELECT 
    MIN([Timestamp]) AS [From],
    MAX([Timestamp]) AS [To],
    Ip,
    User
FROM #mtt
GROUP BY IP, User
ORDER BY IP, [From], [To] DESC, User;
```

And tried as well with windowing which might help, but currently the output is the same:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MIN([Timestamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientIp, UsernameHash ORDER BY ClientIp, [Timestamp]) AS [From],
    MAX([Timestamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientIp, UsernameHash ORDER BY ClientIp, [Timestamp] DESC) AS [To],
    [ClientIp],
    [UsernameHash]
FROM #mtt
GROUP BY ClientIp, UsernameHash, [Timestamp]
ORDER BY ClientIp, [From], [To] DESC, UsernameHash;
```

#### Actual output

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| From             | To               | IP            | User   |
|------------------|------------------|---------------|--------|
| 2018-03-13 08:30 | 2018-03-13 08:30 | 192.168.0.10  | user3  |
| 2018-03-14 01:30 | 2018-03-14 18:00 | 192.168.0.10  | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 11:00 | 2018-03-14 13:50 | 192.168.0.10  | user10 |
| 2018-03-14 01:30 | 2018-03-14 01:30 | 192.168.0.150 | user1  |
| 2018-03-15 08:00 | 2018-03-15 12:20 | 192.168.0.170 | user1  |
| 2018-03-14 10:00 | 2018-03-14 17:30 | 192.168.0.20  | user2  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Including the creation of the temporary table as well:

#### Table creation query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mtt') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #mtt (
        [Timestamp] datetime,
        ClientIp varchar(45),
        UsernameHash varchar(255)
    );
END

DELETE FROM #mtt;
INSERT INTO #mtt([Timestamp], ClientIp, UsernameHash)
        SELECT '2018-03-14 01:30', '192.168.0.10', 'user1'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 07:00', '192.168.0.10', 'user1'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 10:10', '192.168.0.10', 'user1'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 11:00', '192.168.0.10', 'user10'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 10:00', '192.168.0.20', 'user2'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 01:30', '192.168.0.150', 'user1'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-13 08:30', '192.168.0.10', 'user3'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 13:50', '192.168.0.10', 'user10'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 15:30', '192.168.0.20', 'user2'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 17:30', '192.168.0.20', 'user2'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-14 18:00', '192.168.0.10', 'user1'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-15 08:00', '192.168.0.170', 'user1'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '2018-03-15 12:20', '192.168.0.170', 'user1';
```

Lastly to mention, the output records where the `From` and `To` timestamps are identical (e.g. `2018-03-14 01:30 | 2018-03-14 01:30 | 192.168.0.150 | user1` are not mandatory but slightly preferred.

Any ideas for achieving this grouping would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "group-and-islands" problem.  A simple solution uses `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select user, ip, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select mtt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ip order by timestamp) as seqnum_t,
             row_number() over (partition by ip, user order by timestamp) as seqnum_ut
      from #mtt mtt
     ) mtt
group by ip, user, (seqnum_t - seqnum_ut);
```

Why this works is a little hard to explain.  But, if you run the subquery and stare at the results, you'll see that the difference between the two sequence numbers identifies the groups of adjacent records.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This was exactly on the requirement, only that you were so swift I cannot accept it as an answer yet!